# Error: Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'application.scss' for Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, assets, sprockets, precompile

I'm having some issues with Sprockets not finding a file during rake assets:precompile. I haven't had this issue before, but when I added a generated migration (which built locally), Heroku failed to build my app, and I don't know why, because it builds locally (without me running an additional rake assets:precompile).

Error message is this:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Sprockets::FileNotFound: could not find file: /tmp/build_dd4a799769e6963b7b292df72db58fd8/username-appname-uniqueid/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
```

Any help with why this is? Thank you for your time!

PS. As a side note - when I run "rake assets:precompile" and then push to Heroku, the app builds. However, an item with the css class "fa-bars" gets messed up... why is this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does running `rake assets:precompile` locally work?

Comment: Yes, it does. Not sure why it's not working on Heroku

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I add the same issue with Sprockets 3.3.3 and our Rails 4.2.3 app.

I fixed it by cleaning our dyno build cache with:

```
heroku repo:purge_cache
```

Please note that your next deployment will take longer as bundler cache will be cleared too.

Comment: To install the Heroku repo plugin: `heroku plugins:install https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo.git`

Comment: Worked for me. Seems like this is something Heroku might want to look into.

Comment: So glad I found a solution and see am not alone on this

Answer (score 0):

In rails 5 if you use Bower, uncomment in bower_rails.rb

```
  #bower_rails.install_before_precompile = true
```